# How to identify source of requests and which files are being accessed in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We use Firebase for file storage to host images and other media for our users. I'm seeing large spikes in our Cloud Storage egress costs. It looks like Networking Traffic Egress GAE/Firebase Storage is the culprit. I'm trying to understand where these requests are coming from and what files are being accessed during these spikes. Which logging would I need to setup to answer this question and debug the cause for these spikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Access Audit Logs are the right logs to determine this. See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit

You can turn them on by following these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access
IAM & Admin > Audit Logs > search for "storage" > For Cloud Storage for Firebase API and Google Cloud Storage, turn on Data Read and Data Write in the right panel > hit save

Now that you're collecting them, you can view the logs by following instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit
Logging > Logs Explorer > In Query > Resource > pick GCS Bucket for your project
In the Log name filter, select data_access